# Correct way to implement placeholder variables (PEP8)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8

I run into the problem of needing placeholder variables a lot. I try to code according to PEP8, and always follow it, also i am using PyCharm which notifies me about mistakes. Currently i use `_` as i have seen this in a lot of online codes, but i guess it is wrong as i still got the warnings. What is the correct way of doing this?

Some examples:

I need a list (with given length) of tuples where each tuple is (0, None):

```
bound = [(0, None) for _ in ENERGY_ATTRIBUTES]
```

An unordered multiprocess where the function does not return anything

```
for _ in p.imap_unordered(partial(read_energies, round=i), PEPTIDE_KD.keys()):
    pass
```

Also tried

```
_ = [_ for _ in p.imap_unordered(partial(read_energies, round=i), PEPTIDE_KD.keys())]
```

Same warnings.

Comment: Not an answer to the question but solutions for avoiding `_`. For the first one: there's `repeat` in `itertools`: (`repeat((0,None), len(ENERGY__ATTRIBUTES))`). For the second one: just use `list()`.

Comment: The `repeat` is a good solution, but i dont really get the `list()` you mention.

Comment: Instead of a for loop or a list comprehension you can just say `list(p.imap_unordered(partial(read_energies, round=i), PEPTIDE_KD.keys()))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sevanteri, i was searching for something like this. If you post it on an answer i will gladly upvote it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore the warnings if you know they are harmless. They are warnings, not errors or exceptions. If you know what you are doing, ignore or suppress the warnings!

Comment: So there is no "offical" way for placeholders?

Comment: Apart from the use of the `_` variable, not really.

Comment: `pylint` understands `_xxx` naming convention (which includes a bare `_`) for unused variables and does not warn. I think it is a de facto standard.